# Generic type inference not working with dynamic?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, dynamic, type-inference

I have recently been playing with Massive, a Micro-ORM which returns collections of IEnumerable<dynamic>.

I discovered an unexpected issue when I tried to query one of those collections using LINQ.

While the compiler seems to have no issues whatsoever to work out that string.Format returns a string even when one of the arguments passed to it is declared as dynamic...

```
dynamic dynamicString = "d"; // just using a string here for simplicity, same problem occurs with any other type
string explicitString = string.Format("string is {0}", dynamicString); // works without issues
```

...it doesn't appear to be able to infer that fact in the following scenario:

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = new[] { "a", "b", "c" };
IEnumerable<dynamic> dynamics = strings;

IEnumerable<string> output = dynamics.Select(d => string.Format("string is {0}", d)); // compiler error on this line
```

The compiler complains:

```
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<dynamic>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"
```

Since the compiler should be able to infer that my lambda expression returns a string, I would have expected it to also infer that the TResult of the Select should be of type string (and not dynamic).

It was easy to fix by specifying the TSource and TResult explicitly like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> output2 = dynamics.Select<dynamic, string>(d => string.Format("string is {0}", d)); // works !!!
```

Or I could assign the result to an IEnumerable<dynamic>...

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> output3 = dynamics.Select(d => string.Format("string is {0}", d)); // also works
```

I have also confirmed that this problem does not occur when I replace my IEnumerable<dynamic> with an IEnumerable<object>:

```
IEnumerable<object> objects = strings;
IEnumerable<string> output4 = objects.Select(o => string.Format("string is {0}", o)); // works
```

And interestingly even the following works:

```
IEnumerable<string> output5 = dynamics.Select(d => string.Format("string is {0}", (object)d)); // works
IEnumerable<string> output6 = dynamics.Select(d => string.Format("string is {0}", (string)d)); // works
```

Can anybody explain what's going on here? Is this a know limitation of the C# compiler or have I found yet another bug?

Comment: "yet another bug" - there *have been* and indeed *are* bugs in the c# compiler, but very few and far-between. Citing "yet another" is a bit exaggerated, surely?

Comment: I agree that in hindsight my wording does seem exaggerated. I hadn't quite meant it that way but you are right. I was obviously biased as I was subconsciously assessing the likelihood of there being another bug because I had once found an actual bug in the compiler before. (Admittedly it was a very minor issue which will be fixed in the next version). I'm glad that this is not a bug and that I've learnt quite a bit today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need:

```
IEnumerable<string> output = dynamics.Select(d => (string)string.Format(
       "string is {0}", d));
```

It can't infer the return type is `string`, because the `dynamic` means it has to assume the return is `dynamic`, in case there is a more suitable overload of `string.Format` for the specific type supplied (with a different return type). Even if we know otherwise, the spec for `dynamic` will disagree with us ;p By adding an explicit cast back to `string` we make the return type clear.

Personally, I see no use for `dynamic` here; you might as well use `object`, then it isn't an issue in the first place:

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = new[] { "a", "b", "c" };
IEnumerable<object> dynamics = strings;

IEnumerable<string> output = dynamics.Select(d => string.Format(
      "string is {0}", d));
```

(or indeed, leave as `IEnumerable<string>`) I assume you have some other reason to use `dynamic` that isn't visible in this example.

Comment: hmmm... but then why was it happy to do this?
string explicitString = string.Format("string is {0}", dynamicString);

Comment: @BirgerH because of the `string explicitString = ` - which counts as an implicit cast to string (inferring the target type from the assignment). The following would also **compile** (but not run): `XmlDocument doc = string.Format("string is {0}", dynamicString);`

Comment: Thanks Marc! I had misunderstood that aspect of dynamics.(And I still do disagree with it because how could it possibly find a better overload that doesn't return a string?)

Comment: @BirgerH that is the nature of `dynamic`; ***by definition*** overload resolution is suspended until runtime, not compile-time. For info, thinking about it I *actually* prefer `d => string.Format("string is {0}", (object)d)`, since that pins the overload at compile-time, and doesn't involve any needless DLR usage.

Comment: Thanks again Marc. I have really learnt something about dynamic from your explanation. I can now see why it's not even desirable for the compiler to determine the return type in this case. I had originally thought it should be obvious because string.Format is static and all overloads return string (but who is to say there won't be other overloads in the future?). In my real-life example the objects being passed to string.Format were "properties" on an ExpandoObject. That's why I wanted to use dynamic. I am now casting each "property" to its known type explicitly and the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is unrelated to dynamics. I often have a 'user expectation failure' happen when hoping that .Select<> will infer the generic type parameters<sup>1</sup>.

You *could* solve it like so:

```
 Func<dynamic, string> selector = d => string.Format("string is {0}", d);
 IEnumerable<string> output = dynamics.Select(selector);
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> I'll try to add an example of precisely such 'surprisingly ambiguous' cases when I have time later</sub>