# Compile-time error with LINQ Select on IEnumerable<dynamic>

Tags: c#, dynamic, extension-methods, visual-studio-2015, type-inference

**Please see further down for major update!**

---

I have some code like this:

```
void Test(IEnumerable x)
{
  var dynX = x.Cast<dynamic>();
  var result = dynX.Select(_ => _.Text);
}
```

in an existing library project targeted at .NET 4.5. VS2015’s IntelliSense underlines the `Text` part, complaining that: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Text'...

Sure enough, compiling fails with

> error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This message always says `'object'`, even when I change the cast to `.Cast<IAsyncResult>()` or whatnot. When I hover the lambda parameter, the tooltip shows it’s of type `IColumn` (which exists but is unrelated). Again, no matter what type I cast to.

However, when I hover the `Select()` method, it correctly shows the parameter as `Func<dynamic, dynamic>`. If I specify the lambda parameter type explicitly, it compiles. If I specify the type parameters on `Select()` explicitly, it works, too.

Other usages of LINQ with `dynamic` are working. When I copy this method to another (existing) project in the solution, it compiles, too. When I copy it to another file in the same project, it does not compile.

It compiles with VS2013, too.

The very same error appears for all my colleagues as well, both in Windows 8.1 and Windows 10.

Perhaps this is some odd problem with type inference...?

Things I’ve tried that didn’t help:

- Create a new .NET 4.5 library project and re-add files and missing references
- Compare (original) project files—no differences except element ordering

---

**Update**

Well, I managed to create a self-contained minimal *failing* example:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable x = new object[0];
        IEnumerable<dynamic> dynX = x.Cast<dynamic>();

        // CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Text'...
        // var tooltip shows IColumn instead of IEnumerable<dynamic>
        var result = dynX.Select(_ => _.Text);
    }

    public static IColumn Select<TResult>(this IColumn source, Func<object, TResult> selector)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public interface IColumn { }
```

From how I see it, this clearly indicates there’s a serious bug in how VS2015/the new compiler version resolves extension methods.

---

*The following is only loosely related and is mainly about misleading error messages.* I decided to leave it to not make comments confusing.

Even worse, these also fail with the same error, even though neither `IEnumerable` nor `object` could possibly have an extension method `Select()`:

```
// CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Text'
// var tooltip shows IColumn
var result2 = x.Select(_ => _.Text);

object o = new object();   
// CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Text'
// var tooltip shows IColumn
var result3 = o.Select(_ => _.Text);
```

---

**Addendum**

This issue is now tracked on the [Roslyn bug tracker](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5363).

Comment: VS 2010 is not giving any such compile time error!

Comment: Which framework is being used for this project?

Comment: I managed to compile this method fine in VS2015 on both 4.5.2. and 4.6.

Comment: Don't use .NET 4.6 yet.

Comment: It’s targeted at .NET 4.5. I know this code compiles in almost any constellation. It does not compile, however, in the project containing our in-memory data manipulation system.

Comment: "When I copy this method to another (existing) project in the solution, it compiles, too. When I copy it to another file in the same project, it does not compile" - does that not mean there's something in the project that causes the problem? Did you try comparing .csproj files to find out what's wrong with it, it shouldn't be difficult?

Comment: @IgorKorkhov Yes, I recreated the project by hand (copying only the GUID) and re-added all files and references. The error still occurred. Unfortunately, the project contains over 1200 code files, so isolating the problem is very difficult.

Comment: @DanielB: you can copy a .csproj file to a temp folder, then `grep -v \.cs your.csproj` to remove 1200 lines containing references to source code files and then compare, it'll be much easier. I'd also check project *type* GUID in the .sln file to make sure it matches the GUIDs of the other projects

Comment: Do you have a class, variable, or anything else in the scope that could interfere with your code because of the same name?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Thanks for the hint, I finally managed to create a minimal example. I’d be happy if some others could test this and confirm this is indeed a bug.

Comment: I think your issue could be related to this: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4160. I tested your example in both VS2015 and VS2013. In VS2013, `result` works but `result2` and `result3` both fail. In VS2015, all of them fail, but I had different results from the var tooltip. The var tooltip shows that it's an `object` not `IColumn`. I managed to get it to compile on VS2015 when I changed `Func<object, TResult> selector` to `Func<dynamic, TResult> selector` as per the suggestion on the Roslyn issues page.

Comment: Behavior is indeed mysterious and does not compile on 15. However it compiles if Func<object, TResult>  is updated to Func<IColumn, TResult>

Comment: This indeed looks like a Bug. Compiler is totally confused here

Comment: nitpick of statement 'even though neither IEnumerable nor object could possibly have an extension method Select():': IEnumerable or object *could possibly* have an extension method Select()... if you define one. IEnumerable<T> on the other hand very definitely *does* have an extension method Select - which is just the standard LINQ select method.

Comment: @TimLovell-Smith You’re right, of course. Since the compiler behavior on the code in question hasn’t changed all that much, I’m thinking about removing it from the question to remove clutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, seeing how [the bug report](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5363) has been resolved for quite some time, let’s sum it up:

It was a bug, the compiler did not apply the `dynamic` flag as it should, resulting in it becoming an `object`. The bug has been fixed. I don’t know when it will be available in VS2015, perhaps someone else can provide that information.

This probably triggered some quirks in the overload resolution mechanism, resulting in the misleading error messages and tooltip contents.

Answer (score 1):

cant speak to why it works in one VS and not the Other but this is what i would do

rename.

```
public static IColumn Select<TResult>(this IColumn source, Func<object, TResult> selector)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

"Select" is a build in Method Name for other common lib.
so I highly suggest you rename it to something like "AppColumnSelectText" or what ever but not "Select".

then change

```
public interface IColumn { }
```

To

```
public interface IColumn 
{
    string Text {get; set;}
}
```

then implement it

```
public class MyClass : IColumn
{
   public string Text { get; set;}
}
```

Then cast your dynamic to IColumn instead, assuming it come from MyClass class type

```
var columns = fields.Select(a => new {a as IColumn}).ToList();
```

Then your will be able to do

```
var result3 = columns.AppColumnSelectText(x => x.Text);
```

I know this is probably not what you are looking for but the programming is cleaner and you can archive the same result.

### **UPDATE**

Please read the below and comments hopefully this paints a better picture.

```
public static class Test
{
    public static IColumn Select<TResult>(this IColumn source, Func<object, TResult> selector)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static IColumn SelectOtherColumn<TResult>(this IColumn source, Func<IColumn, TResult> selector)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public interface IColumn
{
    string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable ojb = new object[0];
        IEnumerable<dynamic> dynX = ojb.Cast<dynamic>();

        // CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Text'...
        // var tooltip shows IColumn instead of IEnumerable<dynamic>

        //NB this is the System.Linq.Select
        var result = dynX.Select(x => x.Text);

        var xzy = dynX as IColumn;
        //converstion here will probably FAIL so this makes this pointless.


        //here the compliter complains as the Type object has no Text Prop as it was not sepcified anywhere
        var theThingyouwant1 = xzy.Select(x => x.Text);

        //here you are OK as the complier can infer something
        var theThingyouwant2 = xzy.SelectOtherColumn(x => x.Text);
    }

}
```

**Update**
Further to this... See below for illustration perposes

```
public class MyType
{
    public string  Text { get; set; }
    public string  SomethingEsle { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<MyType> ojb = new List<MyType>();
        ojb.Add(new MyType {Text = "OMG", SomethingEsle = "cat"});

        //dynX is a dynamic...
        var dynX = ojb.Select(x => new {x.Text, x.SomethingEsle}).ToList();

        //NB this is the System.Linq.Select
        //this now works as the complier can determine that there is a property Text
        var result = dynX.Select(x => x.Text).ToList();

    }
}
```

You could use your Select... but it only works on something which implements IColumn, which is why i find it hard to see how it would ever work.

Comment: Also beside the point. I’m not asking how to work around this, because that’s trivial. Our method is very similar to `Enumerable.Select`, so why rename it? Also, your naming sense is terrible. ;)

Comment: If you are overriding Select... then OK. But personally I wouldn't do that as i would want to keep Select as is(intact as is)... and create my own slightly different Select(anyway that down to preference). How is your Code going to know about the property Text. When you are in the Select... how is the lambda expression linq going to know about Text at... Compile Time. You don't even specify the Property of the dynamic... so I do not see how it would work anyway...

Comment: PS naming is terrible... as I have no idea... what is meant to do... only you do.... which is why i said... name it what you like ;-)

Comment: looking at that code i would expect the error your getting.... so i don't know how to help... as its seems like you know that. So your not wanting code which works.., your wanting to know why it works in one VS vs why it doesn't in another.... Sozs cant help then, i would expect it to FAIL in both... so im at a loss.

Comment: I’m not overriding `Select`. It’s an extension method on `IColumn`, which has no relation to `IEnumerable<T>` whatsoever. As such, there’s simply no way this error could occur. Unless, of course, there’s an error in the compiler. If you’re confused about how `dynamic` works, you should research it.

Comment: see my update in the original answer i provided... please take note of the code changes.

Comment: That’s not a dynamic object. It’s an anonymous type. That’s something entirely different. `dynamic` resolves all calls at run-time.

Comment: Could you send me working code... I'm really interested to see how this works. As I have toyed around a bit and I'm second guessing without the actual code. in your example code how did you get "var result2 = x.Select(_ => _.Text);" to work on your extension method when its on type IColumn.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90262/discussion-between-seabizkit-and-daniel-b).

Comment: have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951021/generic-type-inference-not-working-with-dynamic?rq=1 it may help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //IEnumerable x = new object[0];
        //var result2 = x.Select(_ => _.Text); 
        //Compile time Error "Enumerable" does not contain a definition for  'Select' and no extension method
       // because IEnumerable is not a generic class

        IEnumerable<object> x = new object[0];
        var result2 = x.Select(_ => _.Text);        
    }
```

Comment: I don’t see how this relates to my question, which is about changed behavior of the C# compiler when resolving extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a case where c# uses a form of duck-typing to allow LINQ to work for any type.

I'll start with a simple example.

If I define a class `Foo` line this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar;
    public int Select(Func<Foo, int> map)
    {
        return map(this);
    }
}
```

I can then write this code:

```
Foo foo = new Foo() { Bar = 42 };

int query =
    from f in foo
    select f.Bar;
```

I get a version of LINQ that works on the type `Foo` (not `IEnumerable<T>`) that returns an `int` (not `IEnumerable<R>`).

All of the LINQ operators can be specifically defined in this way.

The above example can also be written as this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar;
}

public static class Ex
{
    public static int Select(this Foo source, Func<Foo, int> selector)
    {
        return selector(source);
    }
}
```

Now it starts to look like your code.

So if we make this change:

```
public class Foo
{
}

public static class Ex
{
    public static IColumn Select<TResult>(this IColumn source, Func<object, TResult> selector)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public interface IColumn { }
```

Then this code fails with the same error as yours:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> foo = new [] { new Foo() };

var query =
    from f in foo
    select f.Text;
```

If I then make this change:

```
public static class Ex
{
    public static IColumn Select<TSource, TResult>(this IColumn source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The code now reports that "RuntimeBinderException: 'Foo' does not contain a definition for 'Text'".

What we've finally done is show that the compiler tries to implement the LINQ `Select` operator with your `Select` method. It then tries to see if it can use the defined `Select` method as an overload for the types presented and since `dynamic` can be "cast" to `IColumn` it says your `Select` method is the best overload. Also, since the compiler will only search the candidates in the current class it won't go on to find the standard LINQ operator.

Of course, then the compiler, using your overload, casts `dynamic` to `object` and then tries to find the `.Text` property. It can't of course, so it then reports your error.

Comment: I don’t see how a LINQ query syntax example relates to my question. It behaves exactly the same way: It compiles on VS2013 and fails on VS2015. What are you trying to say?

Comment: The fact the compiler tries to implement the LINQ `select` operator from any method called `Select` that implements a variety of supported signatures gives you this odd behaviour. Try changing the name of the method and the behaviour changes.

Comment: It’s not “any method called `Select`”. It’s an instance or extension method `Select(Func<,>)`. However, my `Select` method is not an extension method in `IEnumerable<dynamic>`. As such it simply is not applicable here. Also, I’m not using query syntax.

Comment: @DanielB - It is applicable here. When I changed the signature of your code from `public static IColumn Select<TResult>(this IColumn source, Func<object, TResult> selector)` to `public static IColumn Select<TSource, TResult>(this IColumn source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)` the code in your example compiled just fine. The original code is clearly failing because your `dynX.Select(_ => _.Text)` is calling your `Select` method.

Comment: @DanielB - I did say that it was "any method called `Select` that implements a variety of supported signatures", not just "any method called `Select`".

Comment: It is possible that this is just an overload resolution issue. I would love @EricLippert  to get involved here.

Comment: It is *not* applicable, because `IColumn` has no relation whatsoever with `IEnumerable<T>`. The compiler should never select it, whether you’re using LINQ query syntax or regular extension methods. Just because the bug depends on the `Func<,>`’s type parameters doesn’t make it applicable.

Comment: @DanielB - It does apply. I've shown that this method is being applied as per the above signature change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90442/discussion-between-daniel-b-and-enigmativity).